# One single texture turns out black

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a bit of a weird problem. Im working on a simple road, and sidewalk. Ive applied both the sidewalk texture and the road texture. But here is the problem, the sidewalk texture is showing up perfectly fine in "material-mode" and "realtime render mode", but the road texture only shows up when i render the objects. And here is the weirdest part of all, if i load any other texture to the material instead of the road texture it shows up fine, but as soon as i load back the road texture it turns black again.[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Yes of course! https://sprend.com/download.htm?C=5d34eca9a1014a2db098313f0ef0accd

Comment: For future uploads please use file service which doesn't delete files 2 hours after successful download. In case of Blender.SE you are welcome to use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) service.

Comment: Oh well, didn't even thought of that, but here is a new link, blend-exchange didn't seem to work for me. http://www96.zippyshare.com/v/fZDnyXTh/file.html

Comment: Could you please upload the file somewhere trustworthy, like dropbox? Or at least something that doesnt make my watchguard go all crazy... Anyway at first sight I would say that you can't see the road texture because it wasn't applied in the UV editor window to the mesh, while the other one was. To fix this, go to the UV editor while in edit mode on the black mesh, and select the texture you want to preview on it.

Comment: Well I'm sorry for that, but anyways, i tried fixing it like you said, but now i can't even enter "material mode". Blender just crashes when i try to. But i can enter "texture mode" which shows my different textures blend into one without any problem, so it seems to be some problem with the material itself! I might be completely wrong, but it feels like that is the problem.